# Comparing figures

Tags: comparatives, ielts

We use the adjectives:

**1. big/large/great - small**

**2. high/great - low**

**3. more - less**

when comparing **figures**; for example:

> - The number of people in New York is **higher/bigger/larger/greater** than London.
> - 50 square metres is **greater** than 50 square centimetres.
> - New York has **more** people than London.

**Do we use any other comparative adjectives when comparing them?**

Comment: When comparing _numbers_ (i.e., countable things, rather than uncountable amounts), it is traditionally frowned upon to use _less_. New York has more inhabitants than London, so London has ***fewer*** (not _less_) inhabitants than New York. In casual speech, _less_ is far more common even when referring to countable entities, but in careful speech or writing, it is wisest to avoid it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "greater" and "larger"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62423/difference-between-greater-and-larger) Also [Higher, greater or bigger distance?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39461/higher-greater-or-bigger-distance), and doubtless several others.